# Stray console output on every page

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

It appears that someone in dev forgot to take out some output, because I've been getting this in the console on every page of the main site:

```
//careers.stackoverflow.com/gethired/js?large=true&accountId=4101518
```

Specifically, it comes from line 45 in a file called `loader.min.js`:

```js
return window.careers_adurl
```

It shows up in every page that I have tried so far and [has been reproduced](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2555590#2555590) by another user.

Comment: This should be fixed but in all honesty it's really not a huge deal.

Comment: Just for kicks, I pulled up Math.SE to see if it's on other sites. At any rate, it's not on that one.

Comment: @DennisMeng Yes; I tested it on other sites, but I don't think it is a problem there because Careers is generally associated with Stack Overflow.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Agreed, but I just thought that it was worth reporting since it's an easy fix.

Comment: Not a bug, anyway, the console should be disabled in production by means of modifying the default `console` object in the browser, not removing various successful `console.*` calls

Comment: Well spotted!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That little `console.log` was there for just over a month, on every single Stack Overflow page - so in that time would have polluted something like half a billion browser consoles.

Only one person could save us from the tide of random URL effluent, and that person was me, as it's my turn to fix Careers bugs this week.

That `console.log` is history now. It was defeated with just one crushing blow.

Will we see its like again? Probably. Who will be there to save us next time? Maybe me. Maybe some other hero developer. It depends whose turn it is.